# libvirt-go cross-compiling fails on macos with the GOOS=Linux

Tags: go, libvirt

I have a project using [libvirt-go](https://github.com/libvirt/libvirt-go/) v7.4.0.

go.mod:

```
github.com/libvirt/libvirt-go v7.4.0+incompatible // indirect
```

It compiles on both mac and linux, but cross-compiling fails on macos with the `GOOS=Linux` flag.

```sh
$ env GOOS=linux go build -o myapp .
# gitlab.mycompany.io/mycompany-platform/myapp/command/agent
command/agent/libvirt_listener.go:11:26: undefined: libvirt.DomainEventType
command/agent/libvirt_listener.go:23:14: undefined: libvirt.Connect
command/agent/libvirt_listener.go:100:9: undefined: libvirt.EventRegisterDefaultImpl
command/agent/libvirt_listener.go:105:15: undefined: libvirt.NewConnect
command/agent/libvirt_listener.go:115:4: undefined: libvirt.EventRunDefaultImpl
command/agent/libvirt_listener.go:121:22: undefined: libvirt.Connect
command/agent/libvirt_listener.go:121:42: undefined: libvirt.Domain
command/agent/libvirt_listener.go:121:65: undefined: libvirt.DomainEventLifecycle
command/agent/libvirt_listener.go:149:63: undefined: libvirt.DomainState
command/agent/libvirt_listener.go:121:22: too many errors
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THe libvirt-go package is a CGo binding to the native libvirt platform library. As such it is not possible to disable CGO when building it, and in turn it is not possible to cross-compile as that implicitly disables CGO.